# Diff Classifier - MEF component

Tags: c#, mef, vssdk

I would like to implement a Diff Classifier, so I downloaded the [Diff Classifier](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Diff_Classifier) of the VSSDK Extensibility samples. Running the Diff Classifier extension displays the correct classification colors.

I developed an extension and I would like to add the Diff Classifier. The extension.vsixmanifest consists of two Assets:

- VsPackage (the extension)
- MefComponent (class library which contains the classes of the Diff Classifier extension).

The Diff Classifier colors aren't displayed if the solution is running in the expertimental Visual Studio 2017 Community application.

Do I need to do something special to register the MEF component? I don't know what is going wrong, because I just copied the (3) classes of the Diff Classifier sample to a class library within my solution.

Perhaps you know a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the version of the extension had not been increased. As a result, the (new) Asset - MEFComponent was not loaded in Visual Studio.

So summarized: increase the extension version in order to load new Assets.